# What is the fastest way to the delete lines in a file which have no match in a second file?

Tags: ruby, perl, bash, python-2.7, cjk

I have two files, `wordlist.txt` and `text.txt`.

The first file, `wordlist.txt`, contains a huge list of words in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, e.g.:

```
你
你们
我
```

The second file, `text.txt`, contains long passages, e.g.:

```
你们要去哪里？
卡拉OK好不好？
```

I want to create a new word list (`wordsfount.txt`), but it should only contain those lines from `wordlist.txt` which are found at least once within `text.txt`. The output file from the above should show this:

```
你
你们
```

"我" is not found in this list because it is never found in `text.txt`.

I want to find a very fast way to create this list which only contains lines from the first file that are found in the second.

I know a simple way in BASH to check each line in `worlist.txt` and see if it is in `text.txt` using `grep`:

```
a=1
while read line
do
    c=`grep -c $line text.txt`
    if [ "$c" -ge 1 ]
    then
    echo $line >> wordsfound.txt
    echo "Found" $a
fi
    echo "Not found" $a
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done < wordlist.txt
```

Unfortunately, as `wordlist.txt` is a very long list, this process takes many hours. There must be a faster solution. Here is one consideration:

As the files contain CJK letters, they can be thought of as a giant alphabet with about 8,000 letters. So nearly every word share characters. E.g.:

```
我
我们
```

Due to this fact, if "我" is never found within `text.txt`, then it is quite logical that "我们" never appears either. A faster script might perhaps check "我" first, and upon finding that it is not present, would avoid checking every subsequent word contained withing `wordlist.txt` that also contained within `wordlist.txt`. If there are about 8,000 unique characters found in `wordlist.txt`, then the script should not need to check so many lines.

What is the fastest way to create the list containing only those words that are in the first file that are also found somewhere within in the second?

Comment: Suppose `我` is in `wordlist.txt` but `我们` isn't.  Suppose that `我们` appears in `text.txt` is that a match for `我`?  I.e. are you really matching words, or just arbitrary substrings of Chinese characters, which could be fragments of words?

Comment: My goal is to create a new, shortened wordlist.txt, which does not contain words which do not match, so that later, more complex scripts, which take many hours to do the work, can do their work much more quickly. The new list is about 5% of the original length. If "我们" is found, but “我" is never found in isolation, ideally, the new word list does not show "我", but if this additional check is very difficult to implement, then it is unnecessary.

Comment: Not for nothin' Village, but you keep asking "is there a faster way"?  The frank and honest truth is no, not really.  There's no way faster than brute force to check for a value in an unsorted set, and there never will be.  You can add a bunch of specific criterion to make use of binary searches, but the general case will never be faster than brute force.  Sorry.  Searches are an insanely consumptive process, and tons of research is being done into how to optimize them, but generally they involve ordering the data in some way.

Answer (score 12):

I grabbed [the text of War and Peace](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600) from the Gutenberg project and wrote the following script. If prints all words in `/usr/share/dict/words` which are also in `war_and_peace.txt`. You can change that with:

```
perl findwords.pl --wordlist=/path/to/wordlist --text=/path/to/text > wordsfound.txt
```

On my computer, it takes just over a second to run.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8::all;

use Getopt::Long;

my $wordlist = '/usr/share/dict/words';
my $text     = 'war_and_peace.txt';

GetOptions(
    "worlist=s" => \$wordlist,
    "text=s"    => \$text,
);

open my $text_fh, '<', $text
    or die "Cannot open '$text' for reading: $!";

my %is_in_text;
while ( my $line = <$text_fh> ) {
    chomp($line);

    # you will want to customize this line
    my @words = grep { $_ } split /[[:punct:][:space:]]/ => $line;
    next unless @words;

    # This beasty uses the 'x' builtin in list context to assign
    # the value of 1 to all keys (the words)
    @is_in_text{@words} = (1) x @words;
}

open my $wordlist_fh, '<', $wordlist
    or die "Cannot open '$wordlist' for reading: $!";

while ( my $word = <$wordlist_fh> ) {
    chomp($word);
    if ( $is_in_text{$word} ) {
        print "$word\n";
    }
}
```

And here's my timing:

```
• [ovid] $ wc -w war_and_peace.txt 
565450 war_and_peace.txt
• [ovid] $ time perl findwords.pl > wordsfound.txt 

real    0m1.081s
user    0m1.076s
sys 0m0.000s
• [ovid] $ wc -w wordsfound.txt 
15277 wordsfound.txt
```

Comment: I should mention that for particularly huge text files, the File::Map (http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Map/) module is a good alternative, but it might be a bit trickier to use in this case.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `grep {$_}` before split?

Comment: Freek: It's to grep out empty strings. You get a few of them with that split.

Comment: This looks like it'll work for western languages but how will it cope with Chinese, Japanese and Korean, as this is what Village plans to use the code for.  Remember, with a word list of A, AB and C, a text file containing ABDEFG would produce a results file with two lines; A and AB.  Would this script produce this result?

Comment: swampf0etus: the utf8::all line ensures that all filehandles (both in and out) are utf8, so reading other character sets will be fine. I have a note that the `/[[:punct:][:space:]]/` regex will likely need to be changed depending on the user's needs. In short, this should be a reasonable solution, with a just a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Of course, the input file may be in a different encode, in which case, you need to specify the encode layer properly:

    `open my $fh, '<:7bit-jis', $some_file or die $!;`

Comment: @Ovid You could shorten it a bit using `@is_in_text{@words} = undef;` and later check with `if( exists $is_in_text{$word} )`. This saves you from creating the temporary array `(1) x @words`

Comment: @dgw: I had considered that, but I thought the `$is_in_text{$word}` boolean check read more naturally. Either way, I can't disagree with you :)

Comment: @Ovid As long as the array `@words` is not too large, you are right the `easier-to-read-code` should be preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Just use comm

http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/08/linux-comm-command-brief-tutorial.html

`comm -1 wordlist.txt text.txt`

Comment: I made some test files, but it always prints every word contained in `wordlist.txt`, even if they never appear in `text.txt`.

Comment: isn't it optimal for the inputs to comm to be sorted? `comm -1 <(sort wordlist.txt) <(sort text.txt)` for modern shells . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you:

```
 tr '[:punct:]' ' ' < text.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' |sort -u | grep -f - wordlist.txt
```

Basically, create a new word list from `text.txt` and grep it against `wordlist.txt` file.

N.B. You may want to use the software you used to build the original `wordlist.txt`. In which case all you need is:

```
yoursoftware < text.txt > newwordlist.txt
grep -f newwordlist.txt wordlist.txt
```

Comment: This seems to assume that the words in `text.txt` are separated by spaces and that they use standard punctuation, but as everything is Chinese, Japanese, or Korean, there are no spaces between words and different punctuation symbols are used.

Comment: Would setting the LC* variables have any affect on how this soution works? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

Use grep with fixed-strings (`-F`) semantics, this will be fastest. Similarly, if you want to write it in Perl, use the [`index` function](http://p3rl.org/index) instead of regex.

```
sort -u wordlist.txt > wordlist-unique.txt
grep -F -f wordlist-unique.txt text.txt
```

I'm surprised that there are already four answers, but no one posted this yet. People just don't know their toolbox anymore.

Comment: This finds and prints those lines in `text.txt` that have words in `wordlist.txt`, however, I want to print only those lines in `wordlist.txt` which have a match somewhere in `text.txt`.

Comment: @Village I guess you could add a `-o` to `grep` (display only the matching parts) and make that unique again with `sort -u`.

Comment: @daxim: This won't work in the general case. For example, if your word list contains `foo` and `foobar`, and the text contains `foobar`, this will only return `foobar`. Of course, another search with the matches in the word list could detect such substring matches.

Answer (score 4):

Quite sure not the fastest solution, but at least a working one (I hope).

This solution needs ruby 1.9, the text file are expected to be UTF-8.

```
#encoding: utf-8
#Get test data
$wordlist = File.readlines('wordlist.txt', :encoding => 'utf-8').map{|x| x.strip}
$txt = File.read('text.txt', :encoding => 'utf-8')

new_wordlist = []
$wordlist.each{|word|
  new_wordlist << word if $txt.include?(word)
}

#Save the result
File.open('wordlist_new.txt', 'w:utf-8'){|f|
  f << new_wordlist.join("\n")
}
```

Can you provide a bigger example to make some benchmark on different methods? (Perhaps some test files to download?)

Below a benchmark with four methods.

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'benchmark'
N = 10_000 #Number of Test loops

#Get test data
$wordlist = File.readlines('wordlist.txt', :encoding => 'utf-8').map{|x| x.strip}
$txt = File.read('text.txt', :encoding => 'utf-8')

def solution_count
    new_wordlist = []
    $wordlist.each{|word|
      new_wordlist << word if $txt.count(word) > 0
    }
    new_wordlist.sort
end

#Faster then count, it can stop after the first hit
def solution_include
    new_wordlist = []
    $wordlist.each{|word|
      new_wordlist << word if $txt.include?(word)
    }
    new_wordlist.sort
end
def solution_combine()
    #get biggest word size
    max = 0
    $wordlist.each{|word| max = word.size if word.size > max }
    #Build list of all letter combination from text
    words_in_txt = []
    0.upto($txt.size){|i|
      1.upto(max){|l|
        words_in_txt << $txt[i,l]
      }
    }
    (words_in_txt & $wordlist).sort
end
#Idea behind:
#- remove string if found.
#- the next comparison is faster, the search text is shorter.
#
#This will not work with overlapping words.
#Example:
#  abcdef contains def.
#  if we check bcd first, the 'd' of def will be deleted, def is not detected.
def solution_gsub
    new_wordlist = []
    txt = $txt.dup  #avoid to manipulate data source for other methods
    #We must start with the big words.
    #If we start with small one, we destroy  long words
    $wordlist.sort_by{|x| x.size }.reverse.each{|word|
      new_wordlist << word if txt.gsub!(word,'')
    }
    #Now we must add words which where already part of longer words
    new_wordlist.dup.each{|neww|
      $wordlist.each{|word|          
        new_wordlist << word if word != neww and neww.include?(word)
      }
    }
    new_wordlist.sort
end

#Save the result
File.open('wordlist_new.txt', 'w:utf-8'){|f|
  #~ f << solution_include.join("\n")
  f << solution_combine.join("\n")
}

#Check the different results
if solution_count != solution_include
  puts "Difference solution_count <> solution_include"
end
if solution_gsub != solution_include
  puts "Difference solution_gsub <> solution_include"
end
if solution_combine != solution_include
  puts "Difference solution_combine <> solution_include"
end

#Benchmark the solution
Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('count') { N.times { solution_count } }
  b.report('include') { N.times { solution_include } }
  b.report('gsub') { N.times { solution_gsub } } #wrong results
  b.report('combine') { N.times { solution_gsub } } #wrong results

} #Benchmark
```

I think, the `solution_gsub` variant is not correct. See the comment in the method definition. If CJK may allow this solution, the please give me a feedback.
That variant is the slowest in my test, but perhaps it will tune up with bigger examples.
And perhaps it can be tuned a bit.

The variant `combine` is also very slow, but it would be interestiung what happens with a bigger example.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use Perl;

```
use strict;

my @aWordList = ();

open(WORDLIST, "< wordlist.txt") || die("Can't open wordlist.txt);

while(my $sWord = <WORDLIST>)
{
   chomp($sWord);
   push(@aWordList, $sWord);
}

close(WORDLIST);

open(TEXT, "< text.txt") || die("Can't open text.txt);

while(my $sText = <TEXT>)
{
   foreach my $sWord (@aWordList)
   {
      if($sText =~ /$sWord/)
      {
          print("$sWord\n");
      }
   }
}


close(TEXT);
```

This won't be too slow, but if you could let us know the size of the files you're dealing with I could have a go at writing something much more clever with hash tables

Comment: The `wordlist.txt` file can contain nearly 300,000 lines. The `text.txt` files vary in length, from very short, to millions of characters.

Comment: This takes an age when run against war_and_peace and the unix dictionary.  I'm currently working on a faster hash table version.

Answer (score 4):

First TXR Lisp solution ( http://www.nongnu.org/txr ):

```
(defvar tg-hash (hash)) ;; tg == "trigraph"

(unless (= (len *args*) 2)
  (put-line `arguments required: <wordfile> <textfile>`)
  (exit nil))

(defvar wordfile [*args* 0])

(defvar textfile [*args* 1])

(mapcar (lambda (line)
          (dotimes (i (len line))
            (push line [tg-hash [line i..(succ i)]])
            (push line [tg-hash [line i..(ssucc i)]])
            (push line [tg-hash [line i..(sssucc i)]])))
        (file-get-lines textfile))

(mapcar (lambda (word)
          (if (< (len word) 4)
            (if [tg-hash word]
              (put-line word))
            (if (find word [tg-hash [word 0..3]]
                      (op search-str @2 @1))
              (put-line word))))
        (file-get-lines wordfile))
```

The strategy here is to reduce the corpus of words to a hash table which is indexed on individual characters, digraphs and trigraphs occuring in the lines, associating these fragments with the lines. Then when we process the word list, this reduces the search effort.

Firstly if the word is short, three characters or less (probably common in Chinese words), we can try to get an instant match in the hash table. If no match, word is not in the corpus.

If the word is longer than three characters, we can try to get a match for the first three characters. That gives us a list of lines which contain a match for the trigraph. We can search those lines exhaustively to see which ones of them match the word. I suspect that this will greatly reduce the number of lines that have to be searched.

I would need your data, or something representative thereof, to be able to see what the behavior is like.

Sample run:

```
$ txr words.tl words.txt text.txt
water
fire
earth
the

$ cat words.txt
water
fire
earth
the
it

$ cat text.txt
Long ago people
believed that the four
elements were
just
water
fire
earth
```

(TXR reads UTF-8 and does all string manipulation in Unicode, so testing with ASCII characters is valid.)

The use of lazy lists means that we do not store the entire list of 300,000 words, for instance. Although we are using the Lisp `mapcar` function, the list is being generated on the fly and because we don't keep the reference to the head of the list, it is eligible for garbage collection.

Unfortunately we do have to keep the text corpus in memory because the hash table associates lines.

If that's a problem, the solution could be reversed. Scan all the words, and then process the text corpus lazily, tagging those words which occur. Then eliminate the rest. I will post such a solution also.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty; identifying and fixing that that silly garbage collector behavior was really all the reward I needed out of this.

Answer (score 3):

```
new file newlist.txt
for each word in wordlist.txt:
    check if word is in text.txt (I would use grep, if you're willing to use bash)
    if yes:
        append it to newlist.txt (probably echo word >> newlist.txt)
    if no:
        next word
```

Comment: Can this be made faster by considering the fact mentioned above that many characters appear multiple times in `wordlist.txt`?

Comment: You could use the -L option in grep, which short circuits and closes after the first match.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way with bash script:

1. Preprocessing first with "tr" and "sort" to format it to one word a line and remove duplicated lines.
2. Do this:

cat wordlist.txt | while read i; do grep -E "^$i$" text.txt; done;

That's the list of words you want...

Comment: This is simple, but still takes a long time. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
cat wordlist.txt | while read line
do
  if [[ `grep -wc $line text.txt` -gt 0 ]]
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done

Whatever you do, if you use grep you must use -w to match a whole word. Otherwise if you have foo in wordlist.txt and foobar in text.txt, you'll get wrong match.

If the files are VERY big, and this loop takes too much time to run, you can convert text.txt to a list of work (easy with AWK), and use comm to find the words that are in both lists.

Comment: -w won't work with chinese words... so you have to use regex in this case to make sure each line is matched.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is in perl, maintains your original symantics and uses the optimization you suggested.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@list=split("\n",`sort < ./wordlist.txt | uniq`);
$size=scalar(@list);
for ($i=0;$i<$size;++$i) { $list[$i]=quotemeta($list[$i]);}
for ($i=0;$i<$size;++$i) {
    my $j = $i+1;
    while ($list[$j]=~/^$list[$i]/) {
            ++$j;
    }
    $skip[$i]=($j-$i-1);
}
open IN,"<./text.txt" || die;
@text = (<IN>);
close IN;
foreach $c(@text) {
    for ($i=0;$i<$size;++$i) {
            if ($c=~/$list[$i]/) {
                    $found{$list[$i]}=1;
                    last;
            }
            else {
                    $i+=$skip[$i];
            }
    }
}
open OUT,">wordsfound.txt" ||die;
while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%found) ) {
        print OUT "$key\n";
}
close OUT;
exit;
```

Comment: This is similar to the method I provided, but I don't see any benefit in adding the results to a hash to be iterated and printed at the end. You're spending time (and memory) adding to the hash and then iterating and printing the hash contents when you could just print each result as it's found.  Also, you're slurping entire files into arrays. As these files are potentially quite large, so this could blow the memory.

Comment: I take the requirement is for the result to be shown only once, hence the hash. I tested with a 200k wordlist.txt file, only takes a few seconds to do. Now the poster said wordlist.txt is huge, but text.txt varies. Since the wordlist.txt is sorted, some optimization can be one as the poster suggested.

Comment: I meant 2000k not 200k, based on the assumption wordlist.txt is said to be about 300k lines, CJK words are typically 1-3 characters in length, assuming all words are 3 characters + lineend (8 bytes per line). The memory requirement is about a few megabytes. The optimization is realistic as there are a fairly large number of words start with the same character or some subset of characters.

Answer (score 3):

Use paralel processing to speed up the processing.

1) sort & uniq on wordlist.txt, then split it to several files (X)
Do some testing, X is equal with your computer cores.

```
 split -d -l wordlist.txt
```

2) use xargs -p X -n 1 script.sh x00 > output-x00.txt
 to process the files in paralel

```
 find ./splitted_files_dir -type f -name "x*" -print| xargs -p 20 -n 1 -I SPLITTED_FILE script.sh SPLITTED_FILE
```

3) cat output* > output.txt  concatenate output files

This will speed up the processing enough, and you are able to use tools that you could understand. This will ease up the maintinging "cost".

The script almost identical that you used in the first place.

```
script.sh
FILE=$1
OUTPUTFILE="output-${FILE}.txt"
WORDLIST="wordliist.txt"
a=1
while read line
do
    c=`grep -c $line ${FILE} `
    if [ "$c" -ge 1 ]
    then
    echo $line >> ${OUTPUTFILE}
    echo "Found" $a
fi
    echo "Not found" $a
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done < ${WORDLIST}
```

Comment: This will be uselessly slow on even moderately sized word lists. For each line of the huge corpus of text, you want to grep through the huge wordlist. Also, you're doing the grep the wrong way: you're seeing whether a whole line of text (consisting of many words) occurs in the list of words.

Comment: In the specification, the wordlist contain one word per line. The linux kernel will cache the text file, so it will be quite fast. Yes, I replaced the wordlist/textlist files, I will edit the script. This method can be used with any other scripts, I use shell script here because the requestor seems to understand shell scripts well.